# Unable to log into Bitbucket on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, bitbucket-server

When i tries to log in to Bitbucket (web-based version controller) on Chrome (google chrome web browser), i consistently get,

> Oops, you've made a malformed request.
>   If you came here from a link we sent you, please contact support.

This can happen on Chrome. (works fine on Chrome incognito) This issue occurred when i try resetting my password.

then, i founded a solution from Atlassian Cloud Support. [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloudkb/oops-you-ve-made-a-malformed-request-when-resetting-atlassian-account-password-900816987.html)

but, that's not resolve my problem.

In my research, it seems that people have experienced this error before, but none of worked solution i didn't found.

Any help some else is appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: **It Solved**

Here the answer..

In my case, it was just failing in Chrome, but it worked in incognito mode.

I discovered that it was related to this extension and disabling it fixed the problem: https://poperblocker.com/

Comment: i'm getting "We couldn’t log you in
You may run into this issue when you use specific browsers or add-ons that hide the referer header for id.atlassian.com and other Atlassian sites. Check for these and then try logging in again.". cleared browser cache, disable all extensions, used incognito, used firefox but no success.

Answer (score 3):

First thing - try to log into BitBucket in another browser, or in incognito mode:

- Windows: `ctrl + shift + n`
- Mac: `cmd + shift + n`

If it doesn't work then your best bet is to contact Atlassian support.

But if it works, then it's a big chance that an extension is causing the issue.

What you should do is disable all your extensions (type in the URL bar: `chrome://extensions`) and re-enable each extension, one by one, until you find the culprit.

For me it was this extension causing the problem:

[image: Library Detector v5.6.0]

`Library Detector v5.6.0`

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Same problematic extension for me. I have many extensions that are not affected. [Reported to the author](https://github.com/johnmichel/Library-Detector-for-Chrome/issues/164).

Answer (score 3):

As **snishalaka** mentioned, https://poperblocker.com/ caused my atlassian `Oops, you've made a malformed request` problem. Disable it then login. Finally, you can turn on again.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, just click 'Allow Popups' in the site in your popup blocker plugin and it will work fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because it works in incognito, it sounds like there's some bad caching or something along those lines. Navigate to Bitbucket, open developer tools (menu -> More Tools -> Developer Tools), navigate to the Application tab, and in the top section of the left pane, click Clear storage. Now in the right pane, you should see several checkboxes and a "Clear site data" button. Click that, reload the page, and try again.

Comment: Done with your answer, but that is not a solution in my case. 

In my case, it was just failing in Chrome, but it worked in incognito mode.

I discovered that it was related to this extension and **disabling it fixed the problem** : https://poperblocker.com/

Comment: I too had problems with a chrome extension.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, couldn't login to Atlassian with Chrome. Strangely it was working on incognito. This lead me to checking my Chrome Extensions. One of the extensions I had installed, which was deactivated in incognito, was causing the issue. After removing it, everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

There may be several reasons for this issue. One was, account created earlier and now that was inactive. Other reason can be, login mail used in other bitbucket workspace(in other organization you worked before). So better to send this question to Atlassian support to resolve.
You can raise a question using below form.

[ask bitbucket question](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/forums/postpage/board-id/bitbucket-questions)

[search other bitbucket questions](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/qa-p/bitbucket-questions)

Answer (score -1):

Well the issue for me was due to utorrent extension, soon after i disabled that it started working fine.